# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

Tags: javascript

Why does my javascript throw the following exception

> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

```
function convertToEnd(p) {
        return ((((Number(p)-0)/100-0)*(1.5--0.5)-1.5)* -1);
}
```

Similar questions have been asked before here but as you can see from the various answers, the questions are very different (they usually result in an issue with a 3rd party, where as I have no third party), the only thing in common seems to be the exception string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of:

```
1.5--0.5
```

Change to:

```
1.5- -0.5
```

Alternatively a minifier will convert the whole calculation to:

```
return-1*(2*((Number(p)-0)/100-0)-1.5)
```